# how can I get to decrease loss when the epoch increases?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a problem that the loss does not decrease when the epoch increases.

here is my code

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(None, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
BatchNormalization()


model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, decay=0.001))

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
```

`Total parameters` is number of 10451 and

`train dataset` is number of 2285

I am wondering if the total parameter is a reasonable ratio for train_data.
In other words, I wonder if the total parameter is appropriate to have a ratio of train_data.

and here is my loss graph
[image: 1]

I tried parameter and hyperparameter tuning But this could not be solved.

The dataset has been preprocessed between 0 and 1.

The ensemble rather made the result worse.

how can I get to decrease loss when the epoch increases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no simple answer to your question. You have a loss graph that shows a fast initial learning that then tails off to a much slower reduction after a couple of epochs. This is quite a common phenomenon.

Your question amounts to "how do I make a better machine learning model for this dataset?". Which is an impossible question to answer generically.

Directly you *could* increase layers, weights, etc. Eventually (at least in theory) you would have enough complexity in your model to memorise your entire training set and get the loss down close to 0. The resulting model would almost certainly be overfitted and perform very poorly when it came to data it had never seen before though.

Objectively, if your labels are spread uniformly between 0 and 1, you already seem to have a very low loss value (less than 0.0005 MSE, right??)?

Have you tried this on your test set? It's not at all clear why you need to drive this further down.

Comment: I raised the question because I thought this was not an optimized network. I wondered if there were any network modifications for better performance. For example I didn't know a function like BatchNormalization in the code.
 Adding a layer does not add a layer because it leads to an increase in parameters, which increases the risk of overfitting.

Comment: minimum MSE was 0.0000033043723

Comment: Try to play with different optimizers (there are few ones that has adaptative learning ratio). Also different activaton functions, kernel and bias initializers

Comment: But you should check validation or test accuracy instead in order to evaluate how your model is performing.